# Frame skipping on Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a way to natively enable frame skipping on Flash?

When you develop a game, you develop animations to match the pace of the gameplay, and do it on a target frame-rate (usually 24-40fps for Flash). But if the user's computer is too slow, and cannot maintain the target frame-rate, Flash will automatically lower the fps, making the application play slowly.

If you use a time based logic, the frame based rendering will not match the time based logic, and things will be weird and there'll be a lot of corner cases to work around.

I know by fact that some games use this sort of frame skipping logic, such as Popcap's Zuma Blitz. Are they implementing the frame skipping on their own?

I cannot afford to implement this so late in the project unless I can somehow reimplement the MovieClip class and make it easily frame skipabble. Also, wouldn't the overhead of controlling the animations on your own (overwriting Flash native MovieClip control) be too much of an overhead?

Comment: "My game has 600+ complex MovieClips on the screen, which only about 100 are attached to a as3 class which could have direct control over it." Is your issue that you can't find references to objects once they are added to the stage, or that gotoAndStop() will disrupt the timeline code placed by the artists? You can likely check if too much time has passed, and gotoAndPlay(currentframe+x) if you need to skip x frames and maintain the integrity of timeline code (haven't tested this atm, but also don't know enough about your workflow to say for sure one way or the other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I realize that you're not looking for the following 'solution', which won't work, as all frames will still be played:

```
stage.frameRate = new_frame_rate;
```

The only solution is to just skip frames in your enterFrame callback:

```
// Defined elsewhere.
var current_frame:Number = 0;
var frame_skip_factor:uint; // Skip one frame every 'x' frames.
var is_frame_skip_active:Boolean;

function on_enter_frame(event:Event):void
{
   if ( is_frame_skip_active && current_frame++ % frame_skip_factor == 0) { return; }

   // Game logic/rendering code...
}
```

(assuming, per best practices, you've centralized game logic/animation in a single callback), but that may present race conditions/complications when any asynchronous callbacks are run.

There is no way to actually skip frames at the runtime level; this is part of the contract of the AVM - no frames are skipped, all code is ran, no matter what.  If performance is an issue, you might try asynchronous code execution.  There are a couple of ways to do it:

1) Offload some computing to Pixel Bender, so that it can be processed asynchronously and/or in parallel (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_pixelbender.html)

2) Spread out the execution of lengthy operations over multiple frames (requires a state save and state restore, a la memento pattern).  Details (and a great read) here: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/asyncoperations/

In any case, I'd (first and foremost) recommend definitively identifying the performance bottleneck with a tool like the Flash Builder Profiler or the Stats class (Mr. Doob).

Blitting might be the solution (create a spritesheet with a tile for each frame of the animation) as well.  But in any case, I think what you'll need to do is subclass MovieClip and override the play(), stop(), and gotoAndPlay() methods.  Your class should look something like this:

```
public class MyMovieClip extends MovieClip
{
   override public function play():void
   {
      addFrameSkipListener();

      super.play();
   }

   override public function gotoAndPlay(frame:Object, scene:String = null):void
   {
      addFrameSkipListener();

      super.gotoAndPlay(frame, scene);
   }

   // ....
}
```

Where the frame skip listener will skip frames according to the current frame rate or frame time, if necessary.  Naturally, you'll also need to remove the frameSkipListener when the animation has reached an end.

While the MovieClip override solution might do what you want on paper, if you have a lot of objects, this might actually degrade performance as the additional ENTER_FRAME listeners will add some overhead.

Comment: "There is no way to actually skip frames at the runtime level; this is part of the contract of the AVM - no frames are skipped, all code is ran, no matter what." Very interesting, could you find me a reliable link that says that?
I can't seem to find it in here http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf

Comment: Sure can - the (semi-)famous article (http://ted.onflash.org/2005/07/flash-player-mental-model-elastic.php, and with an AVM2-specific update here: http://ted.onflash.org/2008/04/flash-player-mental-model-elastic.php) comparing Flash to an elastic racetrack says:

"In a sense the player is never lossless, it will always do all the work you ask of it and never defer to a later frame cycle."

As to its reliability/credibility, note that this article was directly referenced in Adobe's "Optimizing Performance for the Adobe Flash Platform" document, also a great read.

Answer (score 9):

The approach to use, is to think of changes in pixels-per-second, instead of pixels-per-frame.
Then you can run your main loop on an EnterFrame. In the enterframe, call getTimer() to get the systemtime in miliseconds. And compare that to the value the last time the script was run. This will let you know exactly the amount of time that passed since the last frame. Use that amount to determine how to move stuff.

Here is an example of that will move a circle the at the same rate regardless of the frame rate:

package

```
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Zachary Foley
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var lastFrame:int = 0;
        private var thisFrame:int;
        private var pixelsPerSecond:Number = 200;
        private var circle:Shape
        private var percentToMove:Number; 
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            circle = new Shape();
            circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 25);
            circle.x = 50;
            addChild(circle);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
        {
            // Get the miliseconds since the last frame
            thisFrame = getTimer();
            percentToMove = (thisFrame - lastFrame) / 1000;
            // Save the value for next frame.
            lastFrame = thisFrame;
            // Update your system based on time, not frames.
            circle.x += pixelsPerSecond * percentToMove;

        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
        }

    }

}
```

If you find that low framerates are impacting the accuracy of collision calculations, the run them separately with a timer. This is just the drawing loop, which is inevitably tied to the frame rate.

And just so you know, you can't for frame skipping in flash. It's handled by the player. The best approach is to adjust your frame rendering technique to accomodate the variable frame rate.

Comment: Hello, I know how to control the logic of the game using the time elapsed since the last frame (that's what I call time based logic on my question). My question has to do with controlling the animation itself (an animation on a MovieClip made by an artist).

Comment: so use gotoAndStop() and calculate the correct frame using gotoAndStop(Math.floor(percentToMove*framesPerSecondOfTheMovieClip)); That way your clip will go to the appropriate frame based on how the much time has passed. Doing the same approach with blitting may grant you a performance boost in some cases.

Comment: But then I'd lose the ability to control the animation on the Flash timeline, making it very hard to have artists develop assets on their own, every single asset would need to have its own controlling class.
My game has 600+ complex MovieClips on the screen, which only about 100 are attached to a as3 class which could have direct control over it.

Comment: @felipe - Not sure what you mean by control animation from the timeline. If you mean have scripts on the timeline get called by the playhead, yes. But that's a pretty sketchy method already due to frame dropping. As for the blitting, have your artists create the animation on the timeline. Just when you game initializes, run a loop that goes through each frame and draws it to a bitmap.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by control animation from the timeline, being able to do a stop() at the last frame, or a MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(targetFrame), things that are not game logic but just animation control used by artists.

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest problem is that you are not blitting.  The artists may still animate on the timeline and export sprite sheets.  I would spend some time seriously understanding the performance limitations surrounding the flash player timeline based animations.  Here are a couple of links to get you started:

- [AS3 Animation Benchmark](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2007/12/23/Flash-AS3-Speed-Tests-Rendering-and-Update-Models/)
- [Blitting Basics](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/07/02/tutorial-as3-the-basics-of-tile-sheet-animation-or-blitting/)

As you can see, controlling the animation from the timeline using gotoAndStop(); is the worse possible method for animation, with regards to the quantity of sprites you are working with.

You could also look into working with the new molehill 2d graphics api, the Starling Framework

To address your question directly, I would second the solution already discussed, performing a buffered render to sprite sheets at runtime.  Depending on the number of sprites required at any point in time, you could swap low animation performance for memory limitations.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into something similar; maybe the following helps in some way:

- gotoAndStop(frame) will immediately execute the actionscript at frame
- you can perform multiple gotoAndStop calls within a single ENTER_FRAME event (or any other event).

As test I created a new AS3.0 project within Flash Pro CS5.5. I created a new MovieClip and expanded the timeline to 23 frames.

At the first frame I added the following code:

```
import flash.events.Event;

// do something every frame
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame);
// let event handler change the playHead
this.stop();

// advance playhead 2 frames every frame
function handleEnterFrame(anEvent: Event): void
{
  trace('* ENTER_FRAME');
  this.gotoNextFrame();
  this.gotoNextFrame();
}

// advance to next frame, show playheads position
function gotoNextFrame(): void
{
  // at last frame?
  if (this.currentFrame < this.totalFrames)
  {
    // no, advance to next frame
    var before: int = this.currentFrame;
    this.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame + 1);
    trace('before: ' + before + ', current: ' + this.currentFrame);
  }
  else
  {
    // last frame, stop updating the playhead
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame);
  }
}
```

At frame 5 I created a key frame and added the code:

```
this.gotoAndPlay(10);
```

At frame 14 I created a key frame and added the code:

```
this.gotoAndPlay(16);
```

After running I got the following trace output:

```
* ENTER_FRAME
before: 1, current: 2
before: 2, current: 3
* ENTER_FRAME
before: 3, current: 4
before: 4, current: 10
* ENTER_FRAME
before: 11, current: 12
before: 12, current: 13
* ENTER_FRAME
before: 13, current: 16
before: 16, current: 17
* ENTER_FRAME
before: 17, current: 18
before: 18, current: 19
* ENTER_FRAME
before: 19, current: 20
before: 20, current: 21
* ENTER_FRAME
before: 21, current: 22
before: 22, current: 23
* ENTER_FRAME
```

I have no idea how efficient or time consuming the above is though. I had to use it only with one MovieClip (at late stage of development it was discovered it would be handy if the main character also could run, but there was no budget for running animations; the character contained footstep generating script in the timeline for correct timing).

In your case you could check how much time has passed since the last ENTER_FRAME and then advance the correct number of frames.

You could create a subclass of MovieClip and use this as base class (to quickly do this, select all MovieClips that require this in the library, right click, properties, adjust base class). For those MovieClips that are already linked for actionscript, the .as file can just be updated by extending from the new MovieClip class.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is nothing built into AS3 to skip movieClip frames at a given interval, or to advance more quickly than normal through a timeline animation.  Games like Zuma are probably either doing it manually, or driving their animations without using the timeline to begin with.

To do it manually, you've got two main options:

**Timeline option:** *(might not worth it, for reasons explained below)* If you're really, absolutely tied to timeline animations, *and* changing frame rates is causing a big problem, *and* you don't have the time or technical freedom to redo your animations with code, you can probably use an Event.ENTER_FRAME listener to call a function from each of the movieClip frames to check stage.frameRate, and skip the next frame or two if the frameRate has fallen.

For example:

```
var preferredFrameRate = 24; //use whatever your timeline animations are set to
function skipFramesIfNeeded() {
    var currentFrameRate = stage.frameRate; 
    var speedDifference = 1 - (currentFrameRate / preferredFrameRate);//value between 0-1
    if(.5 <= speedDifference < .66) {
        gotoAndPlay(this.currentFrame+1);
    } else if(.66 <= speedDifference) {
        gotoAndPlay(this.currentFrame+2);
    }
}
```

There are several big issues with doing it this way, but the worst is that you can only skip whole frames - skipping every other frame will double your speed, skipping every two frames will triple it, and so on. So this will not be nearly as smooth or efficient as driving your animations with code instead of the timeline.  Executing code from every single animation frame may also slow things down even further.

**Code only:** If you can find the time, it would be so much better take everyone else's suggestions. Take your animations off the timeline, and drive them with code.  Keep a settings or multipliers for animation and transition speed, or how many pixels objects move per frame.

You could then store your preferred frameRate, compare it to stage.frameRate, and adjust the multiplier accordingly.  This would allow for smoother gradation in speeds.

For example:

```
var preferredFrameRate = 24; //or whatever you want this to run at
var defaultSpeedMultiplier = 1; 
var speedMultiplier = 1; //this is the multiplier we'll update

function updateAnimationSpeed() { 
    var currentFrameRate = stage.frameRate;  // 18, hypothetically
    var speedDifference = 1 - (currentFrameRate / preferredFrameRate); //.25, or a difference of 25%
    speedMultiplier = defaultSpeedMultiplier  + extraSpeed; 
    //speed multiplier increases from 1 to 1.25 to make up for less frequent frames 
}
```

For artist-created visual states, you could possibly load a numbered set of bitmaps, and switch between them the in the order that you would move from one frame to another.

**Edit:** in theory, you can probably also just detect the change, and change the frameRate back, but if the user's machine can't keep up, Flash would probably ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a hundred or so frames long empty movie clip somewhere on the root of your stage, put a a ten seconds or so long completely silent sound clip in it, and set the sound to stream and loop.

This will in effect give you a hassle free variable framerate in Flash, where each timeline and code based animation anywhere in your file will always run for the exact intended time, skipping frames where necessary, but still executing all the code from the timeline even from visually skipped frames. It's a really simple and hassle free solution, I'm surprised more people don't seem to know about it.